# the sum of fields values from a column with a condition

Tags: mysql

I am quite new to mySQL and need help.
I have a database like this (values are example):

```
name   |region        |population|
----------------------------------
Cuba   |Carribean     |10        |
Ukraine|Eastern Europe|15        |
Belarus|Eastern Europe|9         |
Haiti  |Carribean     |3         |
```

I want to find total population of the region (e.g. all population from Eastern Europe) and print as a table the region name and its total population.

But I have no idea how to find a sum of field value from one column but under condition from another column.

How to to do this query?

Comment: if my answer help to you solve problem , then don't forgot to appreciate my work

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT region, SUM(population) AS population
FROM table 
GROUP BY region
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! That works perfectly!
However I want to understand deeply how it works(I mean precisily AS). could you explain please?

Comment: The "AS" is just an alias you can put for your column. You can name it as you want. For the group by, you really need to read a good tutorial who will explain it far better than me : http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_groupby.asp

Comment: Great! Thanks for an answer!

Answer (score 0):

Try below query:

```
select name , region , sum(population)
from region_table // table_name
group by  name , region
```

May be this will help you.

Comment: NO ! you need to do a "group by" by all the non-aggregate in your select. Only mysql accept this and it's not a good habit